# Short form for the word 'Citation'

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a short form for the word - Citation? I Googled but still can't find one.

EDIT: 'Citation' is not a long word but if my document will mention this word at least 100, it would therefore be great if I can find the short form for it.

Comment: You are looking for **Quote**, maybe?

Comment: "**cit**" is the abbreviation of citation. There is also "**Op. cit.**" worth to mention, which is the abbreviation of the Latin phrase opere citato, meaning "in the work cited".

Comment: Is "citation" such a long word that it needs to be abbreviated?

Comment: 'Citation' is no a long word but if my document will mention this word at least 100 times and therefore would be great if I can find the short form for it.

Comment: I've seen **cites** used as a noun, but I personally don't care for it.  There's also *references*.

Answer (score 1):

There is the abbreviation *cit*, but it is only used in particular contexts; you would not use it in running text, though you would use it in a reference.

There are some near-synonyms. I'm guessing you mean the sense in which *quotation*, *quote*, *extract*, *excerpt*, *passage*, *line*, *reference*, or *piece* could work, though if you mean it in another sense, then *commendation* or *order* or various other terms could be used. You may find that some of these near-synonyms can be used some of the time.

For the most part though I wouldn't worry about it. If your document is using *citation* at least 100 times, it's presumably a document in which it is appropriate to use *citation* at least 100 times. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes say 'I cited that author' but there's no official abbreviated form of citation that I know of.

Comment: I am confused because according to user 'ermanen', "cit" is the abbreviation of citation but you mention that there is no official abbreviation for citation. So, is there or there are none?

Comment: By the way, I notice that the CIT is referring to 'Citation' in this link - http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CIT